# What is causing this SQL Error (ORA-02270)

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, alter-table

I'm trying to add foreign keys to a series of SQL tables which are created in the same document.

The other ALTER TABLE queries work fine, but one is giving me trouble. The relevant code is below

```
CREATE TABLE Bookings
(BookingID       NUMBER(15)       NOT NULL,
 Arrive          DATE             NOT NULL,
 BookingDate     DATE,
 Comments        VARCHAR2(200),
 Depart          DATE, 
 PaymentDueDate  DATE,
 ClientID        NUMBER(10),
 RoomID          NUMBER(5),
 CONSTRAINT BookingIDPK
      PRIMARY KEY (BookingID),
 CONSTRAINT RoomIDCK
    CHECK (RoomID BETWEEN 2000 AND 29000 ));
----
ALTER TABLE Bookings
ADD FOREIGN KEY (RoomID)
REFERENCES Rooms(RoomID);
----
CREATE TABLE Rooms
(RoomID          NUMBER(5)        NOT NULL,
 Rate            NUMBER(7,2)      NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT RateCK
    CHECK (Rate BETWEEN 25.00 AND 99.00 ),
 CONSTRAINT RoomIDCK2
    CHECK (RoomID BETWEEN 2000 AND 29000 ));
```

Any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: The ALTER TABLE appears after the CREATE TABLE ROOMS in the full document, just pasted it in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this is these lines here.

CREATE TABLE Rooms

(RoomID          NUMBER(5)        NOT NULL,

 Rate            NUMBER(7,2)      NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT RateCK

    CHECK (Rate BETWEEN 25.00 AND 99.00 ),

 CONSTRAINT RoomIDCK2

    CHECK (RoomID BETWEEN 2000 AND 29000 ));


ALTER TABLE Bookings

ADD FOREIGN KEY (RoomID)

REFERENCES Rooms(RoomID);


You have not set **RoomID** in your *Rooms* table as . Set it as Primary key first.

Comment: Ah damn, I had it there but overwrote it with the CHECKs. Thanks!